# Automatically pop up reply window when the client open the email

Tags: html, html-email

I'm an email marketer. I was ask to create an email where if the client open the mail, the reply window with specific email address will pop. Do you have any idea what can I use/do?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: whaw. you have to try things first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Email doesn't (thankfully) have a feature that would allow you to do that.

You can have replies go to a different address to the one the mail was sent to with a [Reply-To header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-4.4.3), but you can't hit the reply button for the user. They get to read the email and decide if they want to reply first.